# Importing a C function and re-assigning variables

Tags: python, c, cython

I have a C function which I would like to use in Python, but this function has some variables that belong to an old GUI (**not used anymore**).
Is there a way to import this function to Python and re-assign a value to the GUI variables? How?

For example, let's say I have the following function in C, where inputs is from the GUI:

```c
bool validate() {
  if (inputs->name == "") {
    return false;
  }
  // ...
  return true;
}
```

How can I declare it in cython, in order to make it run in python, and how to override the *inputs* value?
Thanks a lot

**EDIT:**

**ctest.pxd**:

```
cdef extern from "myProj.h":
  bool print()
```

**test.pyx**:

```
def cPrint():
  # Is it possible to modify inputs here or anywhere else??
  return ctest.print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variables are exposed by the C library you should be able to simply add declarations for them to your cython file and then set them appropriately in the function call:

```
cdef extern from "myProj.h":
   bool print()

   struct inputs_t:
      char* name
      ...

   inputs_t* inputs;


def cPrint():
   inputs.name = "abc"
   return print()
```